# Microsoft Edge and <VIDEO>

Tags: html, video

I have looked everywhere online to try and solve this issue.

I have got the following code on my website which works fine on all browsers apart from Microsoft Edge, it simply says that the content is not supported, so it is recognising the video tag.

I'm displaying an MP4 video, codec: H.264, AAC

```
<video width="100%" controls id="slider-video">
              <!-- <source src="img-src/{v2_FOLDER}/theme/GMS_Final.webm" type="video/webm"> -->
              <source src="img-src/{v2_FOLDER}/theme/GMS_Final.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001E, mp4a.40.2"'>
              <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
            </video>
```

As you can see, I have even tried using an webm but this also doesn't work... any ideas?

Updated Code:

```
<video width="100%" controls id="slider-video">
              <source src="http://devsite6.clickserverdev.co.uk/img-src/_themev2-germanmotorspecialist-1131/theme/GMS_Final.webm" type="video/webm">
              <source src="http://devsite6.clickserverdev.co.uk/img-src/_themev2-germanmotorspecialist-1131/theme/GMS_Final.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="http://devsite6.clickserverdev.co.uk/img-src/_themev2-germanmotorspecialist-1131/theme/GMS_Final.m4v" type="video/m4v">
              <source src="http://devsite6.clickserverdev.co.uk/img-src/_themev2-germanmotorspecialist-1131/theme/GMS_Final.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            </video>
```

Comment: I am sure about Edge support mp4 file. So, try to debug a little: check the src is it loading, if u just paste in addressbar. Next thing u can check is the file codec, try to convert it again with some online html 5 video converting tool. And u do not need to describe codecs in type attribute.

Comment: The src is loading fine, however it's not the full path for example: "www.website.com/video.mp4", it's just "/video.mp4" would this make a difference?

Comment: I have just converted my video to m4v, ogg, webm and added these in as seen in edited post, still says it doesn't support any of the video types.

Comment: Can you provide the Edge version?

Comment: Just tried the video from W3Schools and this works, so the video is the issue. Don't understand what the browser needs, I have converted it to multiple formats!

Comment: Depends of codec. How u convert it?

Comment: Can you provide a live link so we can check the encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to use the correct MP4 compression with H264 codec (maximum 720p of resolution) with AC3 audio on it.
Edge is like browsers on iPad/iPhone and needs the same H264 compression style.

Comment: AC3 audio did not work for me. I had to use MPEG4. MP4 compression with H264 codec and MPEG4 audio

Answer (score -3):

Drag and drop your mp4 video file to IE-Edge to play it directly from local file system. So you will be sure if your video correctly converted.