# HTML video tag not working on edge

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I using a simple HTML5  to play mp4 file but it says this file is not supported only on microsoft edge
I have followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/html5/video here is my code:

```
<video width="500" height="300" controls autoplay loop>
 <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
 <source src="video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
 Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

It works fine on opera, chrome and firefox

Comment: "it says this file is not supported" As in, you see the "Your browser does not support HTML5 video." message? Or there's an error in the console?

Comment: @DBS There is no error in console and it says "This type of video file isn't supported" not "Your browser does not support HTML5 video."

Comment: I'd suggest to make a minimal complete example: Are you using XHTML or HTML? Also see the example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility the mp4 file is in the newer H265 / HEVC format which is not supported in Windows 10, Edge or the Movies and Photos App

If the title of the mp4 file contains H265 or HEVC, then you will need to download a media player that supports this new format.

Also you can see more here [Microsoft Edge and <VIDEO>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790265/microsoft-edge-and-video?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

What version of edge are you running?

You could create a you tube video and then include it that way.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
```

Comment: mp4 file doesn't contain H265 or HEVC. I dont wanna use youtube because of projects requirement. its a simple 30 seconds mp4 file without any sound

Comment: Have you considered converting the MP4 to a WebM

Comment: When I go to that path /video.mp4 it says invalid source. If I do Webm it asks me if I Want to download that video

Comment: Outside of the format and path I do not see why your video should not play. Do you have a link to your page for us to see? Or a fiddle? Also verify the mime type of your video. you can verify you video type with either of these. Online Tool: http://mime.ritey.com/  Microsoft Tool: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee453695(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes path is correct it works in chrome n other browser. I did follow that link prior to posting here and it says not supported

Answer (score 0):

Source tags are empty elements and should not be closed. Remove the closures like so:

```
 <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm">
 <source src="video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
```

Comment: You can use explicit self closing tags. You do not have to with html5 /xhtml but you can. Many people think it makes a better readability for humans.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge: 2023 Version 119.0.2151.72 (Official build) (64-bit)

1. HTML5 video controls abruptly stopped working at all after the last Edge update November 2023. Note experimental typical video controls, e.g. (edge://flags/#global-media-controls) are/were not all present in past versions. Yet the HTML5 video controls were functional when placed inside a DIV of html pages.
2. Google Chrome asserts HTML video controls and same MP4 files without issues.
3. Android video controls (Edge) appear unaffected but vertical spacing between DIV via ( are seemingly ignored by Google Chrome but not MS Edge built on the Chrome browser. Some very puzzling logic to say the least.
4. Note iis7-iis10 websites must add mime type (.mp4 video/mpeg) remove any static mime type from web.cfg. Use Internet Information Services Manager to add the missing mime type to correct http:500 errors.

Answer (score -1):

It could just be that media autoplay is turned off in Edge:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPA1hCBUokI&ab_channel=MDTechVideos

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34135835)